# Как настроить VueRouter для пагинации?

Tags: vue.js, frontend

Есть компонент **blog.vue** по адресу **//site.dom/blog** - это первая страница
Как настроить роутер, чтоб при обращении к **/blog/1** - чтоб он ссылался на тот же **blog.vue** но **с параметром page: 1** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как всегда, сначала, паника > stackoverflow > решение нашлось само собой 
https://router.vuejs.org/ru/essentials/named-routes.html

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/user/:userId',
      name: 'user',
      component: User
    }
  ]
})
```

Переход на маршрут

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'user', params: { userId: 123 }}">Пользователь</router-link>
```